# Does SQL Server Enterprise edition contain all the components that Business Intelligence edition has?

Tags: sql-server

Are there any missing components that are available in BI edition but not in Enterprise edition?

Comment: [No](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise edition will contain everything that the BI edition has. You can reference the following link for a comparison of the different editions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx